# SSRS report parametrised

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a tabular report with several conditions. As a case in point, the conditions could be either of these:

X is NULL

X is not NULL

X like '%Y%'

I want to create a kind of drill through report with the capability of selecting one of the above conditions.

Now I am creating three tables and use IIF for the visibility of each. I add the parameter to visibility and by selecting one condition the related table becomes visible and the other two becomes hidden.
But I am thinking of just a single table with a parameter for selecting desired condition.

Comment: So what is the question/problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in your duplicate post:

Instead of using a visibility expression, add it as a filter. This will only show rows that match the expression. You can do something like this:

> Expression: ="TRUE"
>
> Operator: =
>
> Value: IIF(Parameters!Status.Label = "NULL", "TRUE", "FALSE")